# Can we use update() with find() in the laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

When I use `update()` with `find()` and invalid `id` like

```
User::find(100)
     ->update(['is_valid' => true])
```

I got error:

> Error: Call to a member function update() on null

But when I use `update()` with `where` and invalid `id` like

```
User::where('id', 100)
     ->update(['is_valid' => true])
```

It returns `false` as expected. so what is the problem when I use `find()`? How to solve it?

Comment: is id 100  exist in users table .if not second query will return false

Comment: Note that : `find()` will return a **single** model instance, where return the **multiple** collection, so you cant use `update()` method with `find()`. `update()` is a method of [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: My question is why can't use `find()` in `update()`? It works for valid `id` but it doen't work for invalid `id`

Comment: how query can perform update on invalid ids

Comment: @Senthur in that case you need to use `findOrFail()`, because `find()` will return null if `id` doesn't exist, so you will get error on next query

Comment: $user= User::query()->findOrFail(100);
       if($user){
           $user->is_valid=100;
           $user->save();

       }

Comment: @JohnLobo what is the response value we get for invalid `id` in `findOrFail()`??

Comment: @Senthur it will throw an exception that will get converted to a 404 response if I recall correctly

Comment: @apokryfos Then I think if we use `update()` with `where` is best option and we can't easily use `update()` with `find()`. if we use `update()` with `where` then It update correctly return `true` if not return `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to use

```php
User::find(100)
     ->update(['is_valid' => true])
```

this without error you can use `optional()` helper like this

```php
optional(User::find(100))
     ->update(['is_valid' => true])
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional

---

`User::find(0)` ---> `null`

it retrun model instance if data found and if not found it it null so you cannot chain `->update()` on `null` that's why your getting error

`User::where('id', 100)` ----> `eloquent instnace`

it is a laravel `Eloquent` so here you can chain as many function which are avilable in `eloquent`

Comment: Thank @kamlesh What is the return value for invalid id `optional(User::find(100))->update(['is_valid' => true])` ???

Comment: it retrun null read doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional